# Microservice sinatra app and authorization over json api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I'm having trouble with coming up with a good solution. Here's my problem:
I have a sinatra app, serving only views (no database), it's communicating with a backend (rails) where users and their roles are defined. How should I go about restricting menu items based on roles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with oaut and jwt to send over user data :)